# How to create a interactive picture story like the new york times has by based on wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I saw this article by the nyt: https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/06/12/arts/design/robert-frank-americans.html

Is it possible to duplicate the functionality with the zooming pictures, that correspond with the text by using wordpress plugins?
How do they get it so fast, considering the amount of pictures?

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you are probably looking for something like a parallax js
https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax

https://the-goonies.webflow.io/

or probably you can google about parallax websites.